# When comparing two equal variables, the program does not identify that they are equal>

Tags: python

I am comparing two variables, that I know are equal, but found does not = 1 when the comparison is over:

```
asearchid=searchid.get()
asearchid=IntVar()
found = 0
with open ('competitordetails.txt','rU') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
    for row in reader:
        compidfound = row[0]
        compidfound = IntVar()
        if(asearchid == compidfound):
            found = 1
        else:
            found = 0
print(found)
```

I changed the two variables to IntVar, but it is still not working

Comment: when programming, learn to question your assumptions. you think they are equal? are you REALLY sure? print compidfound and asearchid and you'll be surprised. Note: make sure they are the same datatype too. compidfound is a string, what about asearchid?

Comment: 100%, in the file row[0] is 27 and asearchid is one that i input which i inputted 27

Comment: Hard to say without more information. What does your file look like? Have you checked for getting them as different data types? i.e. 2 != '2'. Anyways, you are checking only for the last value in the file. Try printing type(asearchid) and type(compidfound).

Comment: ^ that should be the issue to boot. you reset your "found" variable to 0 for every line where condition is false. effectively just setting the variable for last line. add a print in the if block.